# How can I make a different theme be viewed for logged in users vs guests?

Tags: themes, plugin-recommendation

Well, as the title says is my question.

But more details:
Currently I'm using a "coming soon" plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/underconstruction/) so that any random passer-bys don't see the website looking all weird as I muck around with it trying to make it up.

But ideally I'd like to use one of those minimalistic themes, load up a bit of content (about, contact, location, etc pages), then leave that minimalistic theme up for everybody else to view while I (because I'm the only person who can logged in) am just able to see the actual theme as I make modifications to it.

Any plugins which do that or other easy ways to do it?

Cheers!

====
Update Edit:

I just thought I'd leave an update and say I've found a MUCH cooler plugin than underconstruction. It is: "WP Maintenance Mode"
(the Lego one is ultra cool! Says this "boy" who grew up on a steady diet of Lego, and yes by diet I mean sometimes the Lego blocks got actually ingested!)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

Although it doesn't (hmm... although I could be wrong, perhaps with your own style sheet and excluding a bunch of pages that get linked to from the home then it would get 50% of the way to what I want) do what I asked for in the original question of having multiple pages along with any theme I like (which is different to the one I'm developing and viewing while logged in as Admin), for the purpose of having one single page to let visitors know what is going on it is much superior to UnderConstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the only one who needs to see the actual theme and make modifications on it, then take a look at [**`Theme Test Drive`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/) plugin which allows you to Work with one theme on your blog as administrator, while visitors still use and see the default one.

Comment: Thanks!! That initially looks exactly what I want, *but*... I dare not test using it because it has got a *lot* of worrying comments about it being broken. For instance: http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-plugins/theme-test-drive

Any other suggestions please?

Comment: I can only tell form my experience with the plugin, used in 3 different site and never had a problem.
but the best solution would be to work on a dev environment and leave the live one just the way it is, and when you are done you can upload,push,deploy the changes.